# Uploading to an FTP server

Tags: api, shell, ftp, c++-cli

I am working on a tiny tiny application that just uploads a file to the FTP server. I have reviewed my code, but I am quite unable to locate the problem. Here is the code,

```cpp
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

#include "iostream"
#include <conio.h>

using namespace System;

void UploadFiles(String ^_FileName, String ^_UploadPath, String ^_FTPUser, String ^_FTPPass);

int main ()
{
    // Upload file using FTP
    UploadFiles("c:\\test.html", "ftp://playbabe.tk/public_html/test.html", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx");
    return 0;
}

void UploadFiles(System::String ^_FileName, System::String ^_UploadPath, System::String ^_FTPUser, System::String ^_FTPPass)
{
    System::IO::FileInfo ^_FileInfo = gcnew System::IO::FileInfo(_FileName);

    // Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
    System::Net::FtpWebRequest ^_FtpWebRequest = safe_cast<System::Net::FtpWebRequest^>(System::Net::FtpWebRequest::Create(gcnew Uri(_UploadPath)));

    // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
    _FtpWebRequest->Credentials = gcnew System::Net::NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass);

    // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
    // after a command is executed.
    _FtpWebRequest->KeepAlive = false;

    // set timeout for 20 seconds
    _FtpWebRequest->Timeout = 20000;

    // Specify the command to be executed.

    _FtpWebRequest->Method =System::Net::WebRequestMethods::Ftp.UploadFile;

    // Specify the data transfer type.
    _FtpWebRequest->UseBinary = true;

    // Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
    _FtpWebRequest->ContentLength = _FileInfo->Length;

    // The buffer size is set to 2kb
    int buffLength = 2048;
    array<System::Byte> ^buff = gcnew array<System::Byte>(buffLength);

    // Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
    System::IO::FileStream ^_FileStream = _FileInfo->OpenRead();

    try
    {
        // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
        System::IO::Stream ^_Stream = _FtpWebRequest->GetRequestStream();

        // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
        int contentLen = _FileStream->Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

        // Till Stream content ends
        while (contentLen != 0)
        {
            // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
            _Stream->Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
            contentLen = _FileStream->Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
        }

        // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
        _Stream->Close();
        delete _Stream;
        _FileStream->Close();
        delete _FileStream;
    }
    catch (Exception ^ex)
    {
        //MessageBox::Show(ex->Message, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons::OK, MessageBoxIcon::Error);
        std::cout<<"error";
    }

    getch();
}
```

It gives two errors in Visual C++ 2010 Express,

> Error   1   error C2275: `'System::Net::WebRequestMethods::Ftp'` : illegal use of this type as an expression  C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test1\test1\test1.cpp 70
>
> Error   2   error C2228: left of `'.UploadFile'` must have class/struct/union C:\Users\Me\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\test1\test1\test1.cpp 70

I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Amongst other things, your indentation.

Comment: yea sorry for that and thanks for editing it. and thats not purely c++ but in my college it is generally c++ so .... :( any help please?

Comment: No, it is not C++ at all. It is a related but different language, called C++/CLI. Also, this question is more about C++/CLI syntax than about uploading anything to an FTP site. Please create stripped-down testcases in the future.

Comment: sir i am just a beginner and given this huge thing to work with but i'll be careful in future

Comment: Breaking down a problem into tiny pieces is a good way to do business in any part of life. And you are not a beginner at life. :) (The "sir" is not necessary.. and a bit weird, tbh!)

Comment: UploadFile is a static member of the Ftp class, you need to use :: Try to get a license to the VS2008 edition, the lack of IntelliSense support in VS2010 makes it unnecessarily difficult.

Comment: @Hans: I already wrote that in an answer. :)

Comment: Yah, a comment without a question mark.  The hint about IntelliSense was also meant to be somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know C++/CLI, but the following statement is certainly wrong:

```
_FtpWebRequest->Method = System::Net::WebRequestMethods::Ftp.UploadFile;
```

`System::Net::WebRequestMethods::Ftp` is a type and, as the error message indicates (you could have given us the line number!) you're trying to use it as an expression.

Are you trying to obtain a pointer to a static member function?

Did you thus mean the following?

```
_FtpWebRequest->Method = System::Net::WebRequestMethods::Ftp::UploadFile;
```